# Detecting signs of dementia in EEG signal

Tags: methodology, eeg

I would like to know, how dementia can be recognized in the EEG signal of patients with dementia.

What I have found so far:

According to ([Henderson et al., 2006](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1658150)) subjects with dementia are characterized by a decrease in high frequencies, and an increase of the low frequencies in the EEG.

Are there any more characteristics in the EEG that could be used to detect dementia? Which channels of the EEG will be more influenced by dementia?